# How do I make my code add new inputs on a new line in a document while using the .writelines in python?

Tags: python, text-files, file-handling

So I have a file which I have to use this code in order to write in it.
It needs to be able to do so in a way that adds all new inputs in one iteration on a new line of the text document. I tried to see if this would be done automatically every time I run an instance of my code but the only thing that happens is that the information that I previously put in was replaced by the new info.

```
membership_data = open("C:\\Users\\user\Desktop\Pre-release\membership_data.txt", "w")

def ValidateMemberID(MemberID):
    if len(MemberID) !=6:
        return("Wrong Format")
    elif MemberID[:1] == (MemberID[:1]).lower():
        return("Wrong Format")
    elif MemberID[1:3] == (MemberID[1:3]).upper():
        return("Wrong Format")
    elif (MemberID[3:]).isdigit() == False:
        return("Wrong Format")
    else:
        return("Correct Format")


Name = input("Please input member name")
MemberID = input("Please input member ID")
ValidateMemberID(MemberID)

if ValidateMemberID(MemberID) == "Correct Format":
    NameID = [Name, MemberID]
else:
    print ("Invalid MemberID")

membership_data.writelines(NameID)
membership_data.close()




input()
```

My issue springs up here as I'm not sure what to do.

```
Name = input("Please input member name")
    MemberID = input("Please input member ID")
    ValidateMemberID(MemberID)

    if ValidateMemberID(MemberID) == "Correct Format":
        NameID = [Name, MemberID]
    else:
        print ("Invalid MemberID")

    membership_data.writelines(NameID)
    membership_data.close()
```

My end result is such that I will have any number of records that I can easily add to (which I will organise into a table later) in this format:

```
Ammar Khazal Amm123
John Smith Joh456
Lily White Lil789
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple.
`membership_data = open("C:\\Users\\user\Desktop\Pre-release\membership_data.txt", "w")` has the opening setting as `"w"`, which is write, or overwrite. You just need to change the setting to `"a"` which is appending.

`membership_data = open("C:\\Users\\user\Desktop\Pre-release\membership_data.txt", "a")`
That is what you want for adding another line.